# Modifying Boxed View for Blog Posts

Tags: view, blog

I'm trying to maintain the same Boxed view appearance on the blog site, but rather than keeping the 'Created By' column I would like to replace it with a 'Reviewed By' column. Is there an easy way to change what shows up in Boxed view without losing its general look?

Thanks!